# How to stop all child movieclips inside a movieclip in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have a movieclip which is a character in a game. Inside this movieclips there are several movieclips containing limbs that has an animation. So do anyone have a suggestion on how to gotoAndStop(1); on all the movieclips that are inside the character without having to call on every limb object manually?

The character movieclip contains a total of 20 movieclips on 4 frames, so I just want to stop all of the movieclips inside the character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly (ie: stop all movieclips within another movieclip), this should work:

```
function stopAllClips(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    for (var i:int=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        var clip:MoviceClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if (clip)
            clip.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Just call it like so:

```
stopAllClips(yourMovieClip);
```

Where yourMovieClip is the character.

---

### EDIT

As of Flash Player 11.8 / AIR 3.8, there is a built in method for all DisplayObjectContainers called [stopAllMovieClips](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#stopAllMovieClips()).

```
commonParent.stopAllMovieClips();
```

Keep in mind, this will recursively stop all children and grandchildren, unlike the the original answer which only stops the immediate children.

Comment: This will stop all the children on the 1st level, but it's easy enough to optionally make this recursive to stop ALL children on all levels:`function stopAllClips(mc:MovieClip,recursive:Boolean = false):void
{
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    for (var i:int=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        var clip:MoviceClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if (clip) 
  {
   clip.gotoAndStop(1);
   if(recursive) stopAllClips(clip,true);
  }
    }
}`

Comment: This kind of works, but there's one of the movieclips inside the character that doesn't stop, and I get this error (stop is just a mouse click event): 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Babyanimasjon_fla::MainTimeline/stopAllClips()
 at Babyanimasjon_fla::MainTimeline/stopp()

Comment: looks like simple typo - error at MainTimeline/stopp() - should be stop() i assume

Comment: No it's not that, the function is called "stopp", but that's just a button and nothing else. Just dont understand why every movieclip stops except one.

btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopp);

function stopp(evt){
 
stopAllClips(mc);
}
function stopAllClips(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    for (var i:int=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        var clip:MovieClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        
        clip.gotoAndStop(1);
  
    }
}

Comment: did you try Georges code to make it recursive? perhaps the mc that keeps playing is a grandchild rather than child

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I think :

```
// MovieClip propotype function that stop all running clips (current and inside clips)
MovieClip.prototype.stopAllClips = function():void {
    var mc:MovieClip = this;
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    for (var i:int=0; i<n; i++) {
        var clip:MovieClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if (clip) {
            clip.gotoAndStop(1);
            clip.stopAllClips();
        }
    }
}
```

So it's recursive, and can be called from a MovieClip it-self:

```
myMovieClip.stopAllClips(); // Stop the clip and inner clips
```

---

### EDIT

As of Flash Player 11.8 / AIR 3.8, there is a built in method for all DisplayObjectContainers called [stopAllMovieClips](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#stopAllMovieClips()).

```
commonParent.stopAllMovieClips();
```