# Flash as3 how stop playing child movie clips by mouse event?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I'm having same issue exactly explained in this forum post [How to stop all child movieclips inside a movieclip in AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896655/how-to-stop-all-child-movieclips-inside-a-movieclip-in-as3)

Except my requirement is When user click the pause button current frame holding movie clip child element should gotoAndStop and 25 frame.

Also I'm using a timer function so when user click pause button timer should be stopped. This actually working when I add the following code `myTimer.stop();` however if I clicked the play button I put this one `myTimer.start();`. The issue is from `myTimer.start();` function it's actually starting the timer all over again but I need to resume the timer.

Could any help me out of these issues. ASAP

Comment: What are you using the timer for? And you want to have the currentcount to not reset?

Comment: I'm using timer for move to the nextFrame

Comment: Timer unfortunately does not have a `pause` / `resume` ability so you need to keep a variable when you stop the timer and start it again.

Comment: could you please instruct me how to do that. I'm very new to AS3

Comment: I have posted an answer. See if you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop all your child movieclips you could use the code provided in that answer you linked to in your question:

```
yourButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopAllClips(yourMovieClip);
}

function stopAllClips(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    for (var i:int=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        var clip:MovieClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if (clip && clip.name != 'mc_2')
            clip.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

In order to 'resume` your timer you need to keep a variable so you can 'resume' again.
Something like this:

```
var tempTimerCount:int = 0;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.start();
```

And then when you want to stop:

```
tempTimerCount += timer.currentCount;
timer.stop();
```

And after start and you want to have the value of that timer you need to get the `timer.currentCount + tempTimerCount`;

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, this works great :). However, do you have any idea regarding other issue I'm having. (i.e. Stop playing child movie clips) because still that one is not working.

Comment: no luck, I'm now having the following error `1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MoviceClip.`.  Just to confirm I'm defining my movie clips as follows  `stopAllClips(MovieClip(root).home)`

Comment: Try adding `import flash.display.MovieClip;` to the top of your code.

Comment: You have "MoviceClip" in your code - it should be "MovieClip"

Comment: I think it's working but I've missed a point to explain. Because inside the MovieClip(root).home there are 15 movie clips with in that only 13 movie clip are having the child animation movie clips and the rest are normal movie clips. After adding your code it's trying move all movie clips child frame to the defined frame. Therefore, is there a way to neutrilze that 13 movie clips. FYI: I've added instances name for that movie clips as "mc_2" could this help us out

Comment: I have updated my answer. Instead of `if (clip)` to `if (clip && clip.name != 'mc_2')`. That should probably do it.

Comment: man u should be on the King Flash. Everything is now working fine mac :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```
function stopAll(parent:DisplayObjectContainer){
    for(var i:int = 0; i < parent.numChildren; i++){
        var child = parent.getChildAt(i);        
        if(child.hasOwnProperty('stop')){
            child.stop();
        }
        if(child.hasOwnProperty('numChildren')){
            stopAll(child);
        }
    }
}
```

---

To assign to the button:

```
yourButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)

function onClick(e:MouseEvent){
    stopAll(youMainMovieClip);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but how should I assign this function to a button event?

Comment: Hey When I tried this I'm having following errors, 
`
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChild through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

1119: Access of possibly undefined property numChildren through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.`

`
FYI: I'm importing following object before your code runs
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;`

Comment: Try changing DisplayObject to DisplayObjectContainer

Comment: When I tried your I'm getting this `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChild through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.` FYI: I'm defining my movie clips in the function as stopAll(MovieClip(root).home)

Comment: That should be `parent.getChildAt(i)` not `parent.getChild(i)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it works 100%**

Put this code in your main timeline and called using mouse event
**MovieClip_name.stopAllClips();**

`MovieClip.prototype.stopAllClips = function():void {
    var mc:MovieClip = this;
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    mc.stop();
    for (var i:int=0; i<n; i++) {
        var clip:MovieClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if (clip) {
            clip.stop();
            clip.stopAllClips();
        }
    } }`