# stop all movieclips / stop movie after 30 sec' AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm new in AS3 and i don't no what to do....

i'm working on a banner and i want - after 30 sec' the banner will **stop for good**. no looping all movie-clips freeze !

It must be some clean and simple code not so Sophisticated easy to use.

Need Your Help .
Thanks

Comment: Please show an example of what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Too generic question, we are not here to write code for you!

Comment: @eebbesen hey  : this is example of what i need in AS2 -stop();
var timer = setInterval(StopGame, 30000);

function StopGame(){
 gotoAndPlay(2);
 clearInterval(timer);
}

function stopAllMovies(movie:MovieClip):Void {
 movie.stop();
 movie.onEnterFrame = null;
  for (var i:String in movie) {
   if (movie[i] instanceof MovieClip) {
   movie[i].stop();
   movie[i].onEnterFrame = null;
   stopAllMovies(movie[i]);
   }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to do so:

- set `frameRate` to 0
- use one of the many already functions:

  - http://www.unfocus.com/2009/12/07/stop-all-child-movieclips-in-flash-with-actionscript-3-0/
  - [How to stop all child movieclips inside a movieclip in AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896655/how-to-stop-all-child-movieclips-inside-a-movieclip-in-as3)
- best is to use the built-in feature called `stopAllMovieClips` - [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#stopAllMovieClips())